# Firestore rules with php

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have set rules in firestore database in production mode. All my firestore queries is in php . After setting the rules in firestore database none of my queries is executing.
Rule:-

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /contacts/{someuserID} {
  allow read,create,update, delete: if isLoggedIn();
  
  }
}
  
function isLoggedIn(){
    return request.auth.uid == "{someuserID}";
}
```

This is my php query    :

```
<?php $getdata = $db->collection('contacts')->orderBy('createdAt',"desc")->limit(2)->documents();?>
```

Comment: <?php $getdata = $db->collection('contacts')->orderBy('createdAt',"desc")->limit(2)->documents();?> - This  is my php query.

Answer (score 0):

Security rules have nothing to do with which language you are using. The issue is `request.auth.uid == "{someuserID}"` is comparing UID of requesting user with a constant string `"{someuserID}"` which will be false most likely. Try passing the `someuserID` in the function:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /contacts/{someuserID} {
    allow read, create, update, delete: if isLoggedIn(someuserID);  
  }
}
  
function isLoggedIn(someuserID) {
  return request.auth.uid == someuserID;
}
```

Comment: (request.auth.uid != null )  This rule is also not applying. (request.auth.uid) is getting null  value. How can we  pass the value (request.auth.uid) from firestore.

Comment: The `request.auth` variable is automatically set when the user is signed in to Firebase Authentication. Are you signing in anywhere?

Comment: Unable to create a FirestoreClient: Class 'Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient' not found in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\firebase_demo\firebase\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Factory.php:553 . Now I am getting this error when creating firestore . <?php $firestore = $factory->createFirestore();?>